# Show that for $a \ne 1$, $a > 0$ the sequence $\{x_n\} = n(1-a^{1\over n})$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, monotone-functions

I'm having difficulties with the following problem:

> Let:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_n = n(1-a^{1\over n})\\
> a > 0 \\
> a \ne 1 \\
> n \in \mathbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $\{x_n\}$ is an increasing sequence.

I've already tried some default ways of proving such things with the help of division/subtraction but couldn't infer the right inequality from that. I've also played around with logarithms without any luck.

Could anyone give me a hint? (If it would be "divide" or "subtract" then please show some initial steps because i've already tried some of those).

Also please find the visualization via [this link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5gqpb3kymk).

Comment: So it should work in both $a>1$ and $0<a<1$ cases, is that right? Did you try some of each type numerically? [might be good to include such examples, several terms each]

Comment: @coffeemath not exactly numerically, but i've indeed been looking into a visualization of the sequence [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5gqpb3kymk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, the inequality,
$b^m-1>m(b-1)$    where $m>1,b(\ne 1)>0$.

Now, take $b=a^{\frac{1}{n+1}},m=\frac{n+1}{n}$ and we are done using the above inequality.

Comment: This worked like a charm, could you please point to the source of this inequality, I would like to see its proof?